# Perfoce saving, but not checking in yet

Tags: perforce

I like to verify a question with Perforce users:

In your own workspace in perforce, you check out a file, and save it, but do not check it in yet. This saving shouldn't be globally visible to everyone, right? Since each has his/her own workspace. A colleague thinks that it's globally visible to everyone; even if I haven't checked it in. Your opinion is appreciated.

I thought that is what workspace is for.... buffering and isolating one's play area.

When is the situation above (ie, saved but not checked-in) globally visible to everyone?
(Caveat: Everyone is downloading source-codes into their workspace from the same root branch)

Comment: Is your colleague possibly referring to the file itself and changelist details as opposed to the content of the file?

Comment: I think the content of the file itself.

Answer (score 3):

Correct, the changes are pending thus not visible to everyone yet and are only on your local OS workstation.

In Perforce, users can see all opened (checked out) files 'p4 opened -a' - however the actual content of the changes are not visible to everyone. A user would have to shelve their checked out file changes if they wanted other users to be able to access that file that was modified on their workstation.

EXAMPLE

```
$ p4 opened -a
//depot/Jam/MAIN/src/Build.com#7 - edit default change (text) by testguy@testguy14nstreams
//depot/r1.0/bar#1 - edit change 12119 (text) by testguy@testguy14nstreams
//depot/r1.0/foo#1 - edit change 12119 (text) by testguy@testguy14nstreams
//depot/www/dev/Jam.html#2 - edit change 12116 (text) by admin@admin14streams
//depot/www/dev/Jambase.html#2 - edit change 12116 (text) by admin@admin14streams
//depot/www/dev/Jamfile.html#3 - edit change 12116 (text) by admin@admin14streams
//depot/www/dev/Jamlang.html#2 - edit change 12116 (text) by admin@admin14streams
//depot/www/dev/images/jamgraph-jam.gif#1 - edit change 12116 (ubinary) by admin@admin14streams
//depot/www/dev/index.html#3 - edit change 12116 (text) by admin@admin14streams
```

REFERENCES

- Shelving work in progress
  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.files.html#d0e5537
- 'p4 opened' command
  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_opened.html